PluginError: Failed to resolve plugin for module "@sentry/react-native/expo" relative to "root to project"
I recently upgraded my project from Expo SDK 51 to SDK 52. After the upgrade, I encountered an issue where @sentry/react-native/expo stopped working. If I remove @sentry/react-native/expo from my app config, all other plugins work as expected. However, with it included, Sentry fails to initialize properly.
I've tried a few troubleshooting steps but can't seem to find a solution. Has anyone else faced similar issues with Sentry on Expo SDK 52, or are there any known compatibility issues or workarounds?
app config(without '@sentry/react-native/expo' works):
plugins: [
    [
      '@sentry/react-native/expo',
    ],
    'expo-localization',
    [
      'expo-updates',
    ],
    [
      'expo-camera',
    ],
  ],

metro.config.js:
const { getSentryExpoConfig } = require('@sentry/react-native/metro');

const config = getSentryExpoConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;

tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  },
  "types": ["react", "react-native"],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    ".eslintrc.js", // Include ESLint configuration file
    "jest.config.js", // Include Jest configuration file
    "metro.config.js", // Include Metro configuration file
    "babel.config.js", // Include Babel configuration file
    "commitlint.config.js", // Include Commitlint configuration file
    "App.tsx" // Include Expo entry point
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

package json:
"@sentry/react-native": "~6.1.0",


Can you share Android or/and iOS build logs? Does the Sentry source maps upload fails the build or the source maps just don't get uploaded but the build finishes?
When you say Sentry doesn't initialize properly, do you get any errors or what behavior do you observe?

Fix is change '@sentry/react-native/expo' to '@sentry/react-native'
